# Loading resources correctly in Android app (using openGL)

Tags: android, graphics, resources, opengl-es-2.0, splash-screen

**Background / overview**

My app is an openGL game (Android & written in Java).

I'm unsure of how I should be loading my resources (i.e. loading bitmaps, creating objects etc).

I'm currently doing all of this work in my onSurfaceCreated method (see below for example) - this works OK for my Nexus 10 tablet, everything is done in less than a second.  However, when I run it on an older handset (Galaxy Ace), I get a blank screen for around 3 to 4 seconds before anything happens.  I see this as unacceptable so would like to try to find a way around it.

I know I could maybe put a simple splash in place (even just display 'loading') while it does it's business however my questions here are:

**1)** How do I display anything before everything has loaded?  I mean everything is being loaded in onSurfaceCreated and onDrawFrame doesn't run until after onSurfaceCreated.  So how can I display anything while resources are still loading?

**2)** If I display a simple splash.  On newer / faster devices wouldn't that look a bit rubbish?  I mean the splash will display for a split second only as everything loads so fast on new phones / tablets.  Should I force it to stay on the screen for longer than it needs on faster devices?

**3)** Lastly, a related (and really important) problem - on the older handset, after the game is finally displayed.  For about 10 - 15 seconds, everything is intermittently jerky and stuttering.  The phone is clearly doing something in the background.  (it's *not* that the phone can't handle the graphics because it can.  After that 10-15 seconds, everything runs as smooth as butter).  Any clues as to what may be happening here or how to track the problem down would be really appreciated!! :-)

**Just a side note:** I have read various similar questions on SO, and the wider internet but they all seem to involve using XML layouts (and don't seem to be very easy to implement / successful), I should point out that I am not using **any** XML in my app and would like to solve this problem in code without the use of XML if this is possible.

**Code example**

```
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {

//The following are performed once at game load
//All resources are being loaded / created here
//Load graphics files
res.loadResources(view);
//Create game objects (sprites, collision detection etc)
res.createObjects(view, width, height);
//Recycle bitmaps as they are no longer required
res.Recycle();
//Set initial values variables (required for subsequent methods)
res.setInitialValues();
//Set level layout
res.setLevel();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**1)** If you want to show a splash screen while loading resources, you should do as much loading as possible  on a background thread. This is good practice, freeing up the GL thread to do anything you want, since it's not busy loading resources. Any direct interaction with OpenGL needs to be done on the GL thread, though, like uploading textures or compiling shaders.

Normally you would use an `AsyncTask`for background resource loading that need to interact with the UI thread. However, `GLSurfaceView` does not use the main UI thread for GL, so `AsyncTask` won't work here. We can get similar behavior pretty easily by other means, though. Simply load your resources code on your own background thread and post the result on the GL thread, using `GLSurface.queueEvent()`. Background resource loading can be done in many ways; let's use an Executor with a single background thread for this example. Everything is loaded in `onSurfaceChanged()`, ensuring that it's recreated again if user pauses/stops and starts/resumes the application:

```
private Executor mExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(final int width, final int height) {
    // Let's define a few states for the application; NONE, SPLASH,
    // GAME.
    mRenderState = NONE;

    // Currently, the screen is black. Let's get something on screen as
    // quickly as possible. Create a thread and start loading resources.
    mExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final Resources res = mContext.getResources();

            // Load splash screen resource on background thread.
            final Bitmap splashBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.splash);

            // Splash screen is loaded, post a Runnable that will run on the GL thread.
            mGLSurfaceView.queueEvent(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // Upload splash texture to GL, on GL thread.
                    GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, splashBitmap, 0);
                    // Recycle bitmap. We'll create a lot of bitmaps during loading.
                    // Each bitmap is only needed until we have uploaded it to GL. After
                    // that it's just wasting memory. Especially on older phones.
                    splashBitmap.recycle();
                    // Notify application that the splash screen is loaded,
                    // and it's okay to render it.
                    mRenderState = SPLASH;

                    // Screen is no longer black. User sees a splash screen,
                    // perhaps with a progress bar or a nice animation.

                    // Start loading the other textures.
                    // ...
                    // Texture loading finished.
                    mRenderState = GAME;
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onDrawFrame()
{
if (mRenderState == SPLASH) {
        // Render splash screen and a progress bar.
    } else if (mRenderState == GAME) {
        // Render game.
    }
}
```

**2)** You could measure the time it takes to load the splash screen, and compare it on the fast vs the slow device. If it loads about as quickly as the fast device, just don't set mRenderState to SPLASH, and the user will keep seeing a black screen. Hopefully the black screen will be replaced by the game in less than a second. If you wanted, you could add some more timings while loading resources, and if it takes too long, enable the SPLASH render state.

Also, fading in and fading out the splash screen may annoy the user less than just popping it in and out of view.

**3)** There are several things that could lead to stuttering, but I would check at least these before giving up:

*a)* Memory management. Android limits the memory heap size per process, and older devices have a lot less heap memory per process than newer ones, like 16-32 MB vs 128 MB. That means the Garbage Collector will do a lot more work on older devices, when you're loading many heavy resources. Look in the "logcat" for a lot of messages like these:

```
D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 4027K, 30% free 29173K/41635K, paused 3ms+8ms
```

Either those may simply be your earlier loaded bitmaps getting flushed out of memory, or you're creating a lot of other objects that trigger the GC on older devices. Hopefully this is alleviated by recycling bitmaps while loading.

*b)* Just check if other processes are hogging the CPU, using:

```
adb shell top -m 10
```

This will show the CPU usage of the top 10 processes.

*c)* Run method profiling from "DDMS". Press the little button on the "Devices" tab with three arrows and a red circle, while the game is stuttering. Press it again after a few seconds to get the profiling results. It takes a while to learn how to read the charts, but it will basically tell you which parts of your application are currently using the CPU. Perhaps something is working harder the first 10 seconds. Compare it with a profiling result where everything runs smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

1) You could move a lot of your initialization out into an `AsyncTask`. The first screen wont be shown before the Activity has finished `onCreate()`.

2) Yes and no, depend on how, what and where. A simple screen with some loading information is understandable to most users. Most top games comes with some kind of branding screen anyway.

3) I don't know how you've implemented your code, but my guess that your library or your code is still doing some initialization stuff at this point.

Romain Guy shares some trick to speed up initial loading [here](http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/03/04/speed-up-your-android-ui/).

Comment: Hey @Warpzit, thanks.  Cuple of questions.  I was under the impression that initialisations in openGL (Loading textures etc) could not be done on a separate thread and had to be done on the GL Thread?  Also by 'first screen' do you mean first screen of the game or the splash screen?  Note I'm not loading my resourcing from my Application Class (in onCreate), I'm loading them in my GLRendering class (in onSurfaceChanged) - thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @Zippy I haven't done any games so not an expert on openGL. But I believe it should be possible to load resources enough for an initial screen, display it and continue loading resources in the background (all this on same thread). By first screen I mean splash etc.

Comment: Thanks, I'm still not sure how this would work - if I load just my splash resources in my onSurfaceChanged method, then next method that will run will be my onDrawFrame method (which runs continuously) - it never goes back to onSurfaceChanged, so where would I load the remaining resources from?  That's the problem I'm facing.  it's very confusing! Thanks for your suggestions though.

Comment: @Zippy I can't help you with that, but I know it's possible to load resources on the fly :)